# Convert client UUID to SQL UUID

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm using `go` and the package `uuid` to generate a uuid of type `[16]byte`. However when I try to insert that uuid into my `postgres` column of type `uuid` I get the error `converting argument $1 type: unsupported type [16]uint8, a array`. So apparently I should convert the uuid on the client before I insert it into the db. How should I do that? What type should I convert it to?

In short: What `go` data type will work with `uuid` in `postgres`?

Comment: You could start by trying to use a slice instead of an array.  Just add `[:]` to the Go uuid.  For instance, `db.Insert("blah...", myUUID[:])`

Comment: You may also want to try a string formatted uuid as well.  Since every uuid library I have used implement the Stringer interface, I would try `myUUID.String()` as well if the slice doesn't work.

Comment: @sberry converting to `slice` produced a different error: `pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x83`

Comment: Assuming this is the right project, this may be helpful: https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/483

Comment: Oops. so I was using go.uuid BUT I defined the uuid in my models as `[16]byte` since that was the type in the docs, changing it to the uuid.UUID data type solved the problem without any conversions. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @sberry, I found success. Here are snippets of the code for your benefit (with a PostgreSQL 9.5 database):

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Thing struct {
    ID     uuid.UUID `json:"-" sql:",type:uuid"`
    Name   string    `json:"name"`
}

// For a database table created as such:
// CREATE TABLE things ( 
// id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), 
// name TEXT DEFAULT ''::text
// )

func selectThingssSQL() ([]Thing, error) {
    things := make([]Thing, 0)

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, name FROM things")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        t := &Thing{}
        if err := rows.Scan(&t.ID, &t.Name); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        things = append(things, *t)
    }

    return things, nil
}
```